# XamlParseException when trying to access Resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to use one of the default icons as the content of a button in my Xaml code. I don't really understand what's going wrong because the image loads fine when shown in the UI pseudo-emulator but when I try to deploy it I get a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException thrown if I enter the view.

This is the code which is involved:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="IButton"  Source="/Assets/AppBar/cancel.png"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

 <Button x:Name="AmaemiaButton" Content="{StaticResource IButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"   Margin="375,-45,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="65" Height="65" FontSize="22" Click="AmaemiaButton_Click" Opacity="100" />
```

The first snippet is at the top of the xaml markup, and the button call is inside a Grid & Listview.

I've traced the problem to the 'Content="{StaticResource IButton}"' But can't find the problem with the calling of the resource.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What are the details of the error? Why have you set opacity to 100 (value range is from 0 to 1)?

Comment: Only detail I receive is "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll" I know it breaks at this point because when I chance the content to just "i" it runs fine. There's a problem loading the resource but I don't know what it is.. because it seems to load it fine to show in the example emulator. I also changed the opacity to a valid value and it still breaks at this point.

Comment: Is image property: Build Action set to Content?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It is. I can't figure this out.

Comment: Post inner exception for XAML parse exception here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <ImageSource x:Key="IButton">/Assets/AppBar/cancel.png</ImageSource>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

OR

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <BitmapImage x:Key="IButton"
                 UriSource="/Assets/ApplicationBar.Cancel.png" />

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

---

```
<Button x:Name="AmaemiaButton"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Margin="375,-45,0,0"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="65"
                    Height="65"
                    FontSize="22"
                    Click="AmaemiaButton_Click"
                    Opacity="1.0">
                <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource IButton}" />
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
```

Comment: This gives me a "Error 1 Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.CustomAttributeData' to type 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverterAttribute'"

Comment: Try the second solution in my answer! [More information](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/48aab381-22ec-4ca6-88fb-7ce3e13ea1cc/upgraded-vs2012-with-update2-and-now-my-wp8-project-fails?forum=wpdevelop) about the issue

Comment: The second solution worked! Thanks so much for your help, Roman!