# XamlParseException while assigning to property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

This problem was originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756329/xamlparseexception-when-trying-to-access-resource). Though the OP accepted solution, I still cannot figure out what caused the exception. I've made some further tests and failed.

The code is very simple - Windows Phone App only with xaml content:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="IButton" Source="Resources/firstImage.png"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="first" Content="{StaticResource IButton}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button x:Name="second" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
        <Image Source="Resources/firstImage.png"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

At the first glance, everything looks ok, VS designer shows properly two Buttons with images inside. When I try to deply the App I get the XamlParseException:

> Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.Content'.

**The problem concerns first button - second is running without problem**

Quite strange. I've tried changing Build Action (Resource/Content), cleaning project, without success.

Contrary, very similar WPF application works without issue. You just hit *Run* and see two buttons:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="IButton" Source="Resources/firstImage.png"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="first" Content="{StaticResource IButton}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Button x:Name="second" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
        <Image Source="Resources/firstImage.png"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Has anybody an idea what can be wrong? Both applications (WP/WPF) you [can get here](http://1drv.ms/1hgXOzz).

Answer (score 0):

May be this is the difference

```
<Button x:Name="second" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
<Button.Content>
        <Image Source="Resources/firstImage.png"/>
</Button.Content>
</Button>
```

A Button.Content Tag is extra here .

Also the build action of the image should be set to content here.

This is working in my case atleast.

Comment: That's not the problem. Second button works without issue. Your code of course will work. The problem concerns first button and the fact why it doesn't work. Second button is only a check up if the image file exists and so on.